# Missing action in controller, but not calling that action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following controller:

```
class SearchesController < ApplicationController
  def index
    if !params[:src_client].blank?
      @jobs = Job.joins(:clients).where('client.full_name ILIKE ?', "#{params[:src_client]}%")
      @clients = @jobs.map(&:client).uniq
    end
  end
end
```

the following view:

```
<%= form_tag searches_path :method => 'get' do %>
  <table width=25%>
    <tr><td>Client:</td><td><%= text_field_tag :src_client, nil, :size => 50 %></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan=2 align=center><%= submit_tag "Search" %></td></tr>
  </table>
<% end %>
```

So, when I click the submit button I get the following error.

```
The action 'create' could not be found for SearchesController
```

Why is it trying to call the create action?  What can I do to get it to simply run the search?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a comma in your `form_tag` line, change it to this:

```
<%= form_tag searches_path, :method => 'get' do %>
```

Your problem is being caused because you were effectively passing `:method => 'get'` into `searches_path` and not the `form_tag` so it was defaulting to `:method => 'post'`.